# Can't Install ia32-libs on Debian 8

Tags: debian

I can't install `ia32-libs` on my Debian 8 Jessie.

> root@debian:~# apt-get install ia32-libs
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>
> or been moved out of Incoming.
>
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having both "stable" and "testing" repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` was the main reason of the problem.

1. I removed "stable" repository URLs from the `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
2. `apt-get clean && apt-get auto-clean`
3. `apt-get update`
4. `apt-get upgrade`
5. very simple `apt-get install ia32-libs`